# What is a name of a major scale with raised 2nd degree?

Tags: theory, chords, scales

Assuming a major scale that has a raised 2nd degree and no other alterations: **1 ♯2 3 4 5 6 7 (8)** (for example, in C it will be **C D♯ E F G A B (C)**).

This is a bit unusual due to 2 consecutive semitones between 2nd, 3rd and 4th. Also, the ♯2 here sounds much like ♭3, which is a bit "jazzy" (for example, the 7th chord built on 2nd will be (in C) D♯-F-A-C, which is an enharmonic of F7 chord inversion (E♭-F-A-C)).

I've searched the name of this scale in many sources (just because I find it sounding good), but found nothing. Does it have a specific name?

Comment: Do you have an example of that where `C` is actually a tonic, and little of no occurance of D natural?

Comment: In addition of the answer provided by @Shevliaskovic, I'd recommend looking into the Carnatic scales.  There are over 72 (more like well above 144) scales in that system including the 7 modes we have grown accustomed to seeing in Western music.  I point this out because when people ask "what is this scale" it is often from a Western POV, and other cultures may have invented them outside of Western influence and named them as well.

Comment: Raga are not quite the same thing as scales, they describe expected movements between notes in addition to the notes themselves (and imply an Indian approach to pitch, which is different from our the-note-is-this-exact-frequency approach). I'd generally recommend avoid using Carnatic names to describe Western approximations being used to write non-Carnatic music.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you start the scale from E, it sounds like a [minor Neapolitan scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_scale), which consists of the steps `1  ♭2  ♭3 4  5  ♭6 7  8`. So your scale could be a minor Neapolitan scale starting from the 6th degree, which from the wiki article you can see it is simply called **Ionian ♯2** *. It has exactly the same steps as you mentioned:

[image]

The scale degrees `B C D# E` makes you think of a harmonic minor scale with E as the tonic, but the second degree is flat, unlike the harmonic minor scale.

> The scales are distinguished from the harmonic and ascending melodic
> minor scales by the lowered supertonic or second scale degree
>
> <sub>From the wiki article</sub>

<sub>* The Ionian mode has the same steps as the major scale.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I doubt it has a specific name. I think the best way to look at it is as a major scale with a passing note between the D and E. Some musicians talk about a Blues Scale which has D#/Eb in the key of C but in my experience there is no clearly defined Blues Scale and I think it just adds more confusion to music theory.

Scales are not strict and the major scale in C can still use all the chromatic notes without leaving the scale or confusing the tonality. You probably know this but if not you could look up "passing notes".

Answer (score 1):

In Jazz theory this might be notated as F7 (dom.7) chord and probably part of the Blus scale: C,Eb,F ...). But the upper tetrachord is   the normal major scale.

In traditional terminology this chord is D#,F,A,C -> F,A,C,D# = German 6th chord.

Answer (score 0):

[C Mela Sulini](http://pianoencyclopedia.com/scales/mela-sulini/C-mela-sulini.html)

aka Raga Sailadesakshi, Raga Trishuli, Chulini, [Houzam](https://feelyoursound.com/scale-chords/c-houzam-greece/), Huzam, Dolian, Oprian.

You can answer most questions of this kind by using the [scale finder tool](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/finder.php) and searching for the names you find there (although internet sources for some scales are not very good.)